# Uncaught ReferenceError: generateThankyou is not defined at HTMLFormElement.onsubmit

Tags: javascript, html

I've got a basic enquiry submission form that triggers an e-mail in the contact page of my website. I didn't want it to trigger a new page or a page refresh so I've got the form directing the action to an iframe and that's all working fine however I'm now trying to have an onSubmit (or onClick on the submit button) function that sets the `contactform` div to `display:none;` and the `contactsubmitted` to `display:block;`, however I am receiving the `Uncaught ReferenceError: generateThankyou is not defined at HTMLFormElement.onsubmit` error and I've tried tweaking things but nothing's helping. I've got other html triggers calling on js functions exactly like these ones that are working perfectly so I don't understand what I've done wrong. I've tried looking up similar questions to mine but as a beginner myself it doesn't seem to me like any of them are particularly applicable to my scenario (or at least I can't understand how to apply them to my own code unfortunately). I don't mean to repeat content, if anyone can direct me to a question that does answer this one I'll happily take this down.

HTML;

```
<div id="contactform">
     <iframe name="submission" style="display:none;"></iframe>
          <form action="advancedweb.php" method="post" target="submission" onSubmit="generateThankyou()">
                <h3>
                Name <br><input type="text" name="fname"><br>
                e-mail <br><input type="text" name="email"><br><br>
                Message
                <br><textarea name="comment" id="comment" cols="45" rows="6"></textarea>
                <label for="comment"></label>
                <br>
                <input type="submit" value="Send Message">
                </h3>
          </form>
</div>

<div id="contactsubmitted">
    <h3>Thankyou, <?php echo $_POST["fname"]; ?></h3>
                <br>
                <p>
                    Your message,
                    <br>
                    <?php echo $_POST["comment"]; ?>,
                    has been sent on its way! We'll get back to you as soon as we can!
                </p>
</div>
```

CSS;

```
#contactform {
float: right;
width: 400px;
height: 273px;
}

#contactsubmitted {
display: none;
float: right;
width: 400px;
height: 273px;
}
```

JS;

```
function messageComplete() {
var completedMessage = document.getElementById("contactform");
completedMessage.style.display = "none";
}

function messageResponse() {
var thankyouMessage = document.getElementById("contactsubmitted");
thankyouMessage.style.display = "block";
}

function generateThankyou() {
messageComplete();
messageResponse();
}
```

I'm not sure what the issue is - as I said, I've got other blocks of content that are correctly behaving using the exact same method.

Comment: Where is `generateThankyou` defined? In a `<script>` block in the same page? In an external `.js` file? If so, is that file being included in your HTML page?

Comment: It's in an external .js file linked to my html, and I know it's linked correctly as the other functions (also in that file) are working.

Comment: Make sure your browser isn't delivering a cached copy that might not have the `generateThankyou` function. If you're using Chrome, you can use the *Sources* console to see the contents of files included.

Comment: This can happen if you have placed the functions inside document.ready block. Then it is not visible outside. Place it outside document.ready and it will work.

Comment: Thanks guys, I ended up getting it to work. I appreciate the help.

Comment: @Amelia . So exactly what did you do to correct the error?  It would be awesome if you'd share that so others with the same type of error could learn from the experience.